# sympy division of multivariate polynomials

Tags: sympy

Why doesn't sympy divide this polynomial?

```
>>> import sympy as sp
>>> x,y = sp.symbols("x y")
>>> print(sp.div(y+x,y))
(0, x + y)
```

I was expecting the answer to be `(1,x)` because the quotient is `1` and the remainder is `x`. How can I get sympy to divide polynomials?

What I want is to express some polynomial `p` as `p=aq+r` where `r` is the remainder and `q` is the quotient and `a` is the divisor. In the example above, notice that `y+x=1*x+y` and so it seems to me that we should be able to find that `1` is the quotient of `p` by `x`.

**some more details**

Say I am working over a real multivariate polynomial ring, and say I want to express some polynomial `p` as `p=aq+r` for some non zero polynomial `a` and for some `r` with `deg(r)<deg(q)`. By degree (deg) I mean total degree, that is, the degree of the single variate polynomial that you get when you substitute all variables with `x`. For example, the total degree of `xy^2` is 3. Although such a pair `(q,r)` may not exist, if it does exist, it is unique given `(p,a)`. Here is a proof:

Say `p=aq+r` and `p=aq'+r'` for some `r` st. `deg(r)<deg(a)` and assume `q≠q'`.
By subtracting these equations and rearranging we have `a(q-q')=r'-r`.

Notice that because `q-q'≠0`, we have `deg(a)≤deg(a(q-q'))=deg(r-r')`.
Thus because `deg(r)<deg(a)`, we may conclude that `deg(a)≤deg(r')`.
Thus if there exists such an `r`, this `r` is unique.

I point this out so as to suggest that the computation I am asking for is well defined.
It seems to me that being able to do multivariate polynomial division is a natural feature
that sympy should support. If I am wrong here, please let me know why.

Comment: Curiously `div(x+y,x)` behaves as you expect.

Comment: @hpaulj, I added some more information to my question. Hopefully this helps clarify why I am confused.

Comment: There seems to be some sort of implied order when there are several variables, such that `x+y` is considered to be a poly in `x` but not in `y`, where the order seems to be related to symbol creation order.  The documentation is clearer when there's just one symbol.  There are only a few examples with several symbols.

Comment: The ordering can be made explicit e.g. `div(x+y, x, [x, y])` vs `div(x+y, x, [y, x])`

Comment: You can just simplify the expression instead of using div like `sp.simplify((x**2 - y**2)/(x * (x - y)))`

Comment: It seems like you are asking for Euclidean division but a multivariate polynomial ring is not a Euclidean domain: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain

Comment: @OscarBenjamin, I see that multivariate polynomials rings are not Euclidean, however as I showed in my question, it is possible to do division for real multivariate polynomials in the sense that I described. Although a quotient and remainder may not exist, if they do exist they are unique. If sympy doesn't support this functionality, that is fine, however I just want to verify that it doesn't.

Comment: How would you define "degree"? The result of `div` does satisfy what you say but it works with a "degree" function that prioritises the degree in `x` so that `deg(y) < deg(x + y) = deg(x)` (this is why the generator ordering makes a difference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/basics.html)

> Given a family () of symbols, or other suitable objects, including numbers, expressions derived from them by repeated addition, subtraction and multiplication are called polynomial expressions in the generators .

You need to specify the generators. Because given the expression `y+x`, the machine can NOT figure out which variable is the generator. It can be `f(y) = x+y` or `f(x) = x+y`.

You need to tell it the order of generators is [x,y].

```
print(sp.div(y+x, y,gens=[x,y]))
# (0, x + y)
```

If you set the order of generators to be [y,x].

```
print(sp.div(y+x, y,gens=[y,x]))
# (1, x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am still confused as to the importance of the order of the generators. As I tried to explain in my question under the section "some more details", it seems to me that given a division problem with a particular set of variables (generators), it should be possible to define a unique quotient and remainder if they exist. I am worried that imposing an order on the generators won't give me the result I am looking for. Thanks again.